# do you know any alternative port number for zend server?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-server

do you know any alternative port number for zend server ?
because my port 80 is already occupied by xampp

```
<?php echo "help me install"; ?>
```

Comment: Take 8080 as an alternative port. You need to configure this. Additionally, there are other ports under certain circumstances: http://www.zend.com/en/products/server/faq#faq2

Comment: @sasori Whaa?!? Also, why run both Zend Server and XAMPP?

Comment: sorry, according to the installation wizard, 8080 is also occupied , any othe ports ?, ...@Phil, am running different projects on xampp already, i just wanna try the look and feel of zend server's power without interrupting my xampp ..

Comment: @sasori: You basically can choose any *free* port, take 8888 next or if nothing helps 12345 or ... - I think you get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually Zend Server Administration runs on port 10081 by default and localhost on port 80. If you don't like this or another port, choose any free port you like :). Here is how you check what ports are used, open, closed, etc.

#### Windows

```
netstat -a -n
```

#### Linux

```
netstat -nap
```

---

As hakre commented, [Zend writes the following](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server/faq#faq2) about Zend Server and ports:

**Q: What is my port number?**

In most cases, your Web server's port number will be 80. If your port number is 80, you can omit the  parameter from your URL when browsing to your Web pages (i.e. you can browse to http://localhost/ without specifying a port number).

In the following circumstances, your port number will be different:

- You are running Zend Server on Mac OS X. In this case, the default port number will be 10088.
- You installed Zend Server using the Generic Tarball package on Linux. In this case, the   default port number will be 10088.
- You modified the port number on which Zend Server listens, during or after installation.